# Adding jQuery objects to an empty one

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, collections, addition

I'm trying to iterate thru a list of radio butons in order to find the matching labels and constructing a new object from them, but with this code I'm only getting the first label

```
$target=$();

$radio.each(function(){
    $target = $target.add($source.children('label[for="'+$radio.attr("id")+'"]'));
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$radio.attr("id") will only get the first elements id in the collection.. try using `$(this)` or the second argument in the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)  `function(index,Element)`

```
$radio.each(function(){
    $target = $target.add($source.children('label[for="'+$(this).attr("id")+'"]'));
})
```

or

```
$radio.each(function(i,v){
    $target = $target.add($source.children('label[for="'+$(v).attr("id")+'"]'));
})
```

you can even access it directly by doing `this.id` or `v.id` instead of using `.attr('id')`

Comment: Thanks, this did it!.. and also thanks for the this.id advice. ;)